# How do I hide address bar on ice cream sandwich

Tags: android

I'm playing with `jQuery` Mobile and want to create a full screen web app.

I'm testing it with my `Samsung Galaxy Nexus` with `Ice Cream Sandwich`.  I can't find a way to hide the address bar on the browser. I've done some searching online and found many references saying that the way to do this has changed in Ice Cream Sandwich. However I can't find any information on what has changed and what you now need to do.

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Just +1'ing this really.  I have been trying all sorts of things, mostly to do with scrollTo, if you have a long page its possible.  But full screen HTML (as in exactly the screen size) or smaller seems...difficult if not impossible without accessing a library of device screen resolution and parsing UAs.  Yuck.